# Generate 3D image from Multiple 2D Images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, 3d

If we're to capture an image of a body using four (4) WebCam with a 16 megapixel (1 in the front, 1 in the back and 2 sides(left and right)). Is it possible to make a 3D out of it using image processing?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are asking?Try adding a little bit more information on what you are trying to achieve, what have you done so far and what sort of challenges are you facing. The short answer is yes. Even with [one camera](http://graphics.cs.yale.edu/site/sites/files/shadow.pdf) and less resolution. But talking about all the different methods and applications is not going to be a useful answer.

Comment: We're trying to achieve the body measurement from px to cm. For example from a whole body image, we're to measure the bust of a woman from px to cm in real life, real size. Something like that. Is it still possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 3D model of the scene (<=> the depth) if the two cameras are looking to the same scene. After that you detect/extract the commun points between the two images and do some triangulation so you can recover the z component.
From your installation as you discribe it you can only enlarge the field of view

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this seriously, you should have a look into photogrammetry techniques - or rethink you problem and find out if you really need a full 3D model. For photogrammetry, I assume you would need more than four images.

To convert from pixels to centimeters, a simple scale in the scene you image would be necessary. I think this is the simplest solution to the conversion problem, and since you are obviously free to design the scene where and how the images are acquired, it certainly is the simplest solution.